# Extending Object does require an import

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-config

I've found a lot of information about extending classes with the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`. This works great, but now I have added this code to my Class Library and from now on I need an `import` before it works.

A simple example:

```
Public Module StringHelpers
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function customLengthPlus1(ByVal dt As String) As Integer
        Return dt.Length + 1
    End Function
End Module
```

Is it possible to add a line to the web.config or IIS so I do not need to use `import` in all my files and projects?

I already have a import for my Class Library under `pages -> controls` in the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid that in code-behind classes (.cs files) except for `aspx` pages (or `cshtml` if doing MVC) in which case you can simply add the namespace on the web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Your.Namespace" />
        ...
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @KarlAnderson Sorry, dude. I am in pursuit of my gold badge in asp.net ;) hehe

Comment: No worries, it is all about helping people out.

Answer (score 0):

For `.aspx` pages, you can add items to the web.config, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Data" />
                <add namespace="System.Text" />
                <add namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>  
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But for code-behind, there is no way around this AFAIK.